# What does 제까짓 게 means?

Tags: vocabulary

I found this sentence '제까짓 게 어쩌껬어',
I know what 어쩌겠어 is but i can't figure out what it possibly means because there's not much example for '제까짓 게' and i couldn't find the meaning of that word

Comment: [제까짓](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=75384&nation=eng) is a word meaning "a mere ... at that level." It is also looking down on someone to mention her or him using 것 and 거 that usually refer to a thing.

Answer (score 1):

To just paraphrase it, `제까짓 게` means `someone(he/she)` that the speaker is referring to in a condescending way.

`제까짓 게 어쩌겠어` can be translated something like `What is he/she going to do(?)` in a condescending manner. It is expected that he/she can't do anything about the speaker or situation caused by the speaker.

It could sound a little bit different depending on who says that phrase. If it was used by a speaker unrelated to causes of situation, it could sound more like `he/she can't do anything...` in a helpless way.

To break down,

- `제` here sounds like a dialect of he/she(could be plural) to me.
- `-까짓` is an affix to `제` to address `제` in a condescending manner.
- `게` is a shortened form of `것(thing)`+`이(propositional particle)`.

It is not so often used in conversational Korean - sounds quite snobbish.
I've only heard it from few dramatic scenes in K-drama and Korean literature...

Comment: So just to make sure, by someone(she/he), does that means the speaker is refering to another person or naybe the one they talked to?

Comment: Yes the speaker is referring to someone outside of that conversation. If the speaker wants to address the listener 'you' in a condescending manner, `*네*까짓 게 어쩌겠어` might have been used. Which can be translated like 'What are you going to (about me/about this situation)?' If you can elaborate more on where  you picked up that phrase I think I can explain better.